# Magento 2 JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace | and <pre> tag in json after json response in every APIs

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, json

show JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace | and  tag in json after json response in every APIs;

And

tag is appending after tag in all front end and admin pages and also in ajax response

[image: screenshoots...[![][1]]][send image is here]

Comment: have you found any solution. I have same issue..

Comment: I just install new magento project and customize changes

Comment: hmm..which version you are using?

Comment: Old, but did you find a solution ? For no reason, I have this too now...